# Scipy.optimize check_grad function gives "Unknown keyword arguments: ['args']" error

Tags: python, scipy, args, minimization

I want to use  `scipy.optimize.check_grad` to evaluate correctness of gradients. I specify

```
def func(x, a):
    return x[0]**2 - 0.5 * x[1]**3 + a**2 

def grad(x, a):
        return [2 * x[0], -1.5 * x[1]**2 + 2*a]

from scipy.optimize import check_grad
a = 5 
check_grad(func, grad, [1.5, -1.5], args = (a))
```

And get error

```
Unknown keyword arguments: ['args']
```

Noteworthy args is listed as an argumet in the [help file](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.check_grad.html). Shouldn't this work?

Comment: Note that [`*args`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs) is different than `args` in the definition of a function. In this case, what you should provide is `check_grad(func, grad, [1.5, -1.5], a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*args` just passes the position args to the the `func` and `grad` functions.

You want to just pass the value of the meta parameter, `a`, as the argument after `x0`.

```
def func(x, a, b):
    return x[0]**2 - 0.5 * x[1]**3 + a**2 + b

def grad(x, a, b):
        return [2 * x[0], -1.5 * x[1]**2 + 2*a + b]

from scipy.optimize import check_grad
a = 5 
b = 10
check_grad(func, grad, [1.5, -1.5], a, b)
```

See https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/a81bc79ba38825139e97b14c91e158f4aabc0bed/scipy/optimize/optimize.py#L736-L737 for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks -- however, what do I have to do if I have multiple arguments to be passed to `func`. If I add an additive `b` to `func` for example, and call `check_grad(func, grad, x0 = [3, -3], a, b)` then I get error `positional argument follows keyword argument `

Comment: You can't name `x0` in the arg list for that to work.  If you remove `x0=` it will work fine to pass multiple arguments.  When you name `x0`, python thinks you have moved on to the `**kwargs`.

Comment: This is very subtle. I understand now.